# Facebook Comments Widget Display Issues When Not Logged Into Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, comments

We are running into an issue with the Facebook Comments widget and visitors who are not logged into Facebook on a iPhone and Android devices. Instead of showing the FB login button and any comments made by other visitors, the animated loading Facebook loading bar (four rectangles filling left to right) is displayed.

The page we are trying to implement this on is currently under development, so I cannot share a link yet. The same issue, however, is seen on other sites:

http://www.burlingtonfreepress.com/comments/article/20120302/NEWS02/120301032/alburgh-overpayment

http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/lanow/2011/08/kelly-thomas-beating-death-1.html#comments

The device I'm seeing this  is an iPhone 4 running the iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: how you created Facebook comment widget in app? I won’t to do the same  for my iPad App too. Please can you help me out.